# Loop in ruby to textfile

Tags: ruby, file, loops, text

Im trying to make a text file with a lot of number's. 
My code I do have now is fine, but I would like to make a loop where the user will be able to add in more than just 1 number after the first that has been entered. 
This is my code so far.

```
outFile = File.new("Demo.txt", "a+")
  puts "Please submit the number"
  A = gets
outFile.puts A
outFile.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would ensure you are not in an infinite loop, so you can stop with `exit`, `Exit`, `quit` or `Quit` and still have your functionality

```
outFile = File.new("Demo.txt", "a+")
puts "Please submit the number"
while true
  input = gets.chomp
  break if input.match(/^(ex|qu)(?:it)$/i)
  outFile.puts input
end
outFile.close
```

Comment: Consider using `/^(ex|qu)it$/i` otherwise an entry of `corexit` will end the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! exactly what I was thinking about :)

Comment: @user3143672 give me my basket of goodies, by accepting my answer and upvoting it, thanks

Comment: haha, sorry man, im new on stackoverflow, I need 15 rep to upvote :/

Comment: @user3143672 once you have it don't forget to come back and fill my basket

Comment: Or `break if input.match(/^(ex|qu)(?:it)$/i); outFile.puts input` rather than `if..else..end`.  Just a matter of style.

Comment: I've been looking a little at the code, is there any way I can get the program to show, what's inside the text file?

Comment: `puts File.read("Demot.txt")` would print out the content of the file to terminal